# Are variable names in Python valid file names?

Tags: python, filesystems

I want to use the name of variables as file names. Are there any cases in which this might not work?

example:

```
my_var = "value" 
with open("my_var.txt", 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(my_var, fp)
```

Here "my_var" is both a part of a file name and the name of a variable.

So basically I'm asking if python allows any characters in variable names, that would make trouble in filenames.

Comment: It is valid. `"my_var"` in string is string and not variable.

Comment: That highly depends on the OS and file system. In most cases it will valid but very long names could be troubling.

Comment: that would depend on the filesystem. Characters would be OK, but in python you can define a very long variable name, that would be an issue in Windows for instance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may vary for other OSes, but under Windows, all the reserved (forbidden) characters for file names are also not allowed within Python variable names:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

However, there are a few different problems: Certain names are not allowed as Windows file names, specifically:

```
CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9
```

So, you can't name a file `CON.txt` under windows even though `CON` would be a perfectly valid variable name in Python.

Then, there is a length limit for filenames, so very long variable names might cause a problem.

Lastly, Python variable names may be comprised of a wide range of Unicode characters, not all of which may be available for filenames.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx for reference.

Comment: DOS device names are reserved in the final component of classic DOS paths only. This is implemented in the user-mode runtime library (in ntdll.dll) by rewriting the path as a local device path (e.g. "C:\Temp\con.txt" => "\\.\con"). DOS device names are not reserved in local-device paths (i.e. paths prefixed by "\\.\" and "\\?\") and UNC paths. For example, we can create "\\?\C:\Temp\con". However, it's not recommended because most programs will use the classic DOS path "C:\Temp\con" that translates to "\\.\con".

Comment: The kernel does not reserve the wildcard characters `*?"<>`, nor `:`, `|` and control characters (1-31) in filenames. Almost all filesystem drivers (except the named pipe filesystem) reserve the wildcards to properly support WINAPI `FindFirstFile`. But they don't all reserve `:`, `|`, and control characters. The VirtualBox shared-folder filesystem allows them. However, Microsoft's filesystems disallow them, which is so fundamental that they may as well be reserved in the kernel. In particular, NTFS reserves `:` for file stream names, so we need to be vigilant about avoiding `:` in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python variable names can only contain underscores, letters, and numbers they could all be used as file names.

The one issue that could come up, although hard to imagine, is that you could have a Python variable name longer than some file systems allow.  (260 characters in Windows)